# What are the addresses in core files?

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

This is part of my core file:

```
[New Thread 30385]
[New Thread 30383]
[New Thread 30381]
[New Thread 30379]
[New Thread 30378]
[New Thread 30270]
[New Thread 30268]
Core was generated by `test'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x001cd1a6 in ?? ()
```

Does it mean my program crashes at 0x001cd1a6 or the program crashes while trying to read/write to that address?
There is no executable code at that address.
Another thing is it gives a different address every time it crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it mean my program crashes at 0x001cd1a6

Yes.

> There is no executable code at that address.

Well, that would certainly cause a crash (due to illegal instruction).

> Another thing is it gives a different address every time it crashes.

Your program has threads, so its allocation pattern is likely different every time it runs, as threads are scheduled differently.

Also, Linux uses address randomization, so if you run even non-threaded program multiple times, you'll end up with different addresses. On the other hand, GDB disables that randomization, so if you run non-threaded program under GDB, it should crash in the same place every time.

You are likely calling a virtual function on an object that has been invalidated (e.g. deleted). Use `where` GDB command to find out *how* you end up on invalid address.

Also, don't *ever* call your executable `test` on UNIX: this conflicts with `/usr/bin/test`, which many shell scripts will use.

Comment: As long as he doesn't install it, and it isn't in the `PATH`, it's no big deal. And, who would do that to a test program? Besides, `test` is usually a shell builtin.

Comment: +1. I'd upvote again if I could for mentioning the naming conflict with `/usr/bin/test`. It's unexpected things like that which cause endless debugging for no benefit.

Comment: Employed Russian, I think you should write a debugging book.  I would certainly buy it.  I've been observing your answers on here and I can say they're nothing short of excellent.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @bruce.banner I am afraid I don't have much to add to http://www.amazon.com/Debugging-David-J-Agans/dp/0814474578 (which is very good).